# Replacing only specific match's group using Java regular expressions by (new Matcher..).replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, replaceall

Good day to all!
Using (Java) regular expressions, I'm trying to execute [Matcher] replaceAll to replace only a specific group, not all matches. Can you tell me how to do it in **JAVA**? Thank you very much in advance!

```
static void main(String[] args) {
        String exp = "foofoobarfoo";
    
        exp = Pattern
                .compile("foo(foo)")
                .matcher(exp)
                .replaceAll(gr -> "911" + gr.group(1) + "911");

        
        System.out.println(exp);        
    }
```

expecting : foo**911foo911**barfoo

actually
resulted  : **911foo911**barfoo
(Because *replaceAll* applied the replacement string to all matches, namely the groups gr.group(0) (**foo foo** bar foo) and gr.group(1) (**foo** bar foo). And it is necessary to replace only gr.group(1), without gr.group(0)).

How to select a specific group to replace in a string from a regular expression.

Please tell me how it is done correctly. Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: What should be result of `foofoofoofoo`? Which `foo` should be *replaced*? Only 2nd and 4th or maybe we should also replace 3rd since it had `foo` before?

Comment: I am asking since in your example you could also use look-behind mechanism like `(?<=foo)foo` and as replacement `.replaceAll(gr -> "911" + gr.group() + "911");` but this aside from replacing 2nd and 4th `foo` would also replace 3rd one changing `foofoofoofoo` into `foo911foo911911foo911911foo911`.

Comment: yes!, the question is about replacing exactly the 2th foo. 
String exp = "-3 + -8.567 * 10";
        
        exp = Pattern
                .compile("(^|\\D)(-\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)")
                .matcher(exp)
                .replaceAll(gr -> gr.group(1) + "(0" + gr.group(2) + ")");
                
        System.out.println(exp);
I have now tried to frame the brackets with a unary minus. In the replacement expression, you need to use all the groups found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the first `foo`, too:

```java
exp = Pattern
                .compile("(foo)(foo)")
                .matcher(exp)
                .replaceAll(gr -> gr.group(1) + "911" + gr.group(2) + "911");
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/h1NqtN).

Since there are two capturing groups now - `(foo)(foo)` - there are now two `gr.group()`s in the replacement: `gr.group(1) + "911" + gr.group(2) + "911"`.